# cmd команда в php

Tags: php, cmd

Мне необходимо в своем php скрипте в цикле выполнять windows cmd команду
icacls

В терминале я выполняю `icacls \\FS\folder\file.txt /inheritance:e`
Команда включает наследование на указанном файле.

Как мне выполнить правильно эту команду?

Пробовал `system('icacls \\FS\folder\file.txt /inheritance:e')`
или 
`exec('icacls \\FS\folder\file.txt /inheritance:e');`

Но ни ошибок, ни результата не получаю, подскажите как сделать правильно?

Comment: Наверное `exec`, а не `exce`?

Comment: @robertobadjo да, это опечатка просто, результата я не получаю

Comment: Ну если ошибок нет, то наверно она ничего не возвращает. В терминале что-то возвращает?

Comment: @robertobadjo в терминале возвращает:
Успешно обработано 1 файлов;

в php в exec пробую передать вторым параметром $var, но в нее возвращается пустой массив

Comment: Сделайте `echo '\\FS\folder\file.txt';` - посмотрите что выводит. Пропадет один слеш. Экранируйте слеши \\ два раза: \\\\. Может в этом проблема, а может нет.

Comment: 2. `shell_exec` и `exec` являются разрешенными функциями в php.ini? 3. после включения display_errors и error_reporting есть ошибки?

Comment: @Total Pusher, я пробовал выводить '\\\\FS\\folder\\file.txt', экранизируя спеши. Проблема та же. 
shell_exec и exec не отключены в директиве disable_function.
display_error и error_reporting включены в php.ini
Примечательно что результат простых команд вроде echo exec('date') или echo exec('dir') я получаю на  экране, а вот все что сложнее - уже нет. 
Apache запущен под пользователем локального администратора.
Может ли быть проблема в том что exec выполняется не от имени администратора?

Comment: Судя по описанию, нужны повышенные права, `icacls` - это административная утилита (в Linux для аналогичных действий точно нужны). Какой код возврата `$return_var` возвращает [exec](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.exec.php), это третий аргумент по ссылке? Из под обычного непривилегированного пользователя с консоли нормально отрабатывает?

Answer (score 1):

После суток разбирательств нашел решение:
В переменных среды я перезаписал значение переменной PATH на %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp, перезапустил Apache и все заработало.

Comment: Так вы пытались права к временному каталогу настроить? А какой путь был до этого в этой переменной, ради интереса? Опять же, подозрение на разделение прав, и таким способом вы перенесли каталог в "область прав" обычного пользователя.

Comment: Total Pusher, если честно я уже забыл какой был путь? так как сервер до меня настраивали, я решил его задействовать в благих целях.
Я так понял что у меня проблема была просто в том, что пользователю под которым был запущен Apache не хватало прав на выполнение С:\Windiws\System32\

Answer (score 0):

Там есть второй параметр куда надо по ссылке передать переменную. там и будет результат выполнения.

http://php.net/manual/ru/function.exec.php

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7093860/php-shell-exec-vs-exec

Comment: в php в exec пробую передать вторым параметром $var, но в нее возвращается пустой массив

Comment: Пробовал Shell_exec, результат тот же, я не получаю никакой ошибки.
При этом упростил команду до:
$cmd = `icacls C:\\Folder\\file.txt /inheritance:e'
В терминале отрабатывает, а через Shell_exec($cmd) не дает результат

Comment: попробуйте для начала с любой системной командой типа dir или echo

Comment: Shell_exec('date') обрабатывается нормально, а вот с Shell_exec('ipconfig') тоже не дает ответ

Comment: если запустить в терминале руками из произвольной папки и разных разделов "icacls \\FS\folder\file.txt /inheritance:e" что выводит?

Comment: есть подозрение что программа завершается с ошибкой, тогда вы получаете вывод в std.Err вместо std.Out

Comment: находясь в терминале в любой папке, выполняя 
\\FS\folder\file.txt /inheritance:e  всегда срабатывает и выводит Успешно обработано 1 файлов; не удалось обработать 0 файлов

Comment: В обоих случаях это принимает терминал, но в случае с программами для них это 2 раздельных вывода.
выше указанные функции обрабатывают только stdOut
попробуйте http://php.net/manual/ru/function.passthru.php

Comment: ну и если и это не поможет тогда через обратные кавычки $output = \`dir\`;

Comment: c passthru тоже самое, что и со всеми предыдущими командам.
В случае с $output = 'echo dir'; passthru($output); я получаю на экране просто dir

Comment: все функции перепробовали, я сдаюсь)